# transform guid to string for sas put statement

Tags: sas

The following code should print a guid to the log:

```
%let test = %sysfunc(uuidgen());

data _null_;
 put &test.;
run;
```

For some reasons the put line fails. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `%`:

```
%put &test.;
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Comment: Why would you have a `%put` statement within a datastep?  That does not make any sense.

Comment: Agreed, the dataset wrapper doesn't add anything. I think @csetzkorn ultimately found what he was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113190/create-unique-file-name-in-sas-using-guids and this was just an interstitial question about printing macro variables

Answer (score 0):

The `put` statement in the datastep prints either variables or a string literals.

In your case you have a value within a macro variable that you would like the `put` statement to interpret as a string literal.  You can do this by wrapping it in quotes:

```
data _null_;
  put "&test";
run;
```

If you want to use the macro `%put` statement.  You can just replace the whole datastep with:

```
%put &test;
```