# create unique file name in sas using guids

Tags: sas

I am currently trying something along those lines in SAS:

```
%let PartialString = %sysfunc(uuidgen());

%let OUTFILE = /SomeFolder/FileName_%SYMGET(&PartialString.).csv;
```

The second line throws errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need %SYMGET.

```
50         %let OUTFILE = /SomeFolder/FileName_&PartialString..csv;
51         %put &=outfile;
OUTFILE=/SomeFolder/FileName_077e90fb-4877-67c7-9e86-b1e2779cf868.csv
```